# how to execute 2 threads in the same time using semaphore

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

i created 2 threads for 2 trains , the first has (nord-sud) direction and the second has (sud-nord) direction, so there is only one railway, can't meet 2 trains with different direction ..
so here is my main class :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {        
        Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1); 
 
        MyThread train1 = new MyThread(sem, "nord-sud"); 
        MyThread train2 = new MyThread(sem, "sud-nord"); 
         
        // stating threads 1 and train 2 
        train1.start(); 
        train2.start(); 
        train1.join();       
        train2.join();
    }
```

and here is my MyThread class extended Thread class :

```
class MyThread extends Thread 
{ 
    Semaphore sem; 
    String threadName; 
    public MyThread(Semaphore sem, String threadName)  
    { 
        super(threadName); 
        this.sem = sem; 
        this.threadName = threadName; 
    } 
  
    @Override
    public void run() { 
          
        // run by thread A 
        if(this.getName().equals("nord-sud")) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Starting " + threadName); 
            try 
            { 
                System.out.println(threadName + " wait for railway to enter"); 
              
                // acquiring the lock 
                sem.acquire(); 
              
                System.out.println(threadName + " have access to enter"); 
          
                // Now, accessing the shared resource. 
                // other waiting threads will wait, until this  
                // thread release the lock 
                for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) 
                { 
                    Shared.count++; 
                    System.out.println(threadName + ": " + i); 
          
                    // Now, allowing a context switch -- if possible. 
                    // for thread B to execute 
                    Thread.sleep(1000); 
                } 
            } catch (InterruptedException exc) { 
                    System.out.println(exc); 
                } 
          
                // Release the permit. 
                
                System.out.println(threadName + " left the railway "); 
                sem.release(); 
                
                
        } 
          
        // run by thread B 
        else
        { 
            System.out.println("Starting " + threadName); 
            try 
            { 
                // First, get a permit. 
                System.out.println(threadName + " wait for railway to enter"); 
              
          
                sem.acquire(); 
              
                System.out.println(threadName + " have access to enter"); 
          
                for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) 
                { 
                    Shared.count--; 
                    System.out.println(threadName + ": " + i); 
          
              
                    Thread.sleep(1000); 
                } 
            } catch (InterruptedException exc) { 
                    System.out.println(exc); 
                } 
                // Release the permit. 
                System.out.println(threadName + "left the railway"); 
                sem.release();
        } 
    } 
   
}
```

so when i add 2 trains with nord-sud direction for exemple in the same period, i want them to both get enter to railway because they have same direction, the train should wait only when he realize that another train with different direction is in the railway. so how can i execute 2 threads in the same time  ? for exemple train1(nord-sud), train2(nord-sud), and train3(sud-nord) . so both train 1 and train 2 enter to railway and train 3 wait them to leave to get access.

Comment: Why the `if... else...` block ? You run exactly the same code in both branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two permissions for trains with similar directions and one permission for trains with different directions, for example:

```
public class Solution0 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    String direction1 = "nord-sud";
    String direction2 = "sud-sud";
    int permissionCount;
    if (direction1.equals(direction2)){
        permissionCount = 2;
    }else {
        permissionCount = 1;
    }
    Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(permissionCount);

    MyThread train1 = new MyThread(sem, direction1);
    MyThread train2 = new MyThread(sem, direction2);

    // stating threads 1 and train 2
    train1.start();
    train2.start();
    train1.join();
    train2.join();
}
```

}

output for different direction:

```
Starting sud-sud
Starting nord-sud
sud-sud wait for railway to enter
nord-sud wait for railway to enter
sud-sud have access to enter
sud-sud: 0
sud-sud: 1
sud-sud: 2
sud-sud: 3
sud-sud: 4
sud-sudleft the railway
nord-sud have access to enter
nord-sud: 0
nord-sud: 1
nord-sud: 2
nord-sud: 3
nord-sud: 4
nord-sud left the railway
```

output for a similar direction:

```
Starting sud-sud
Starting sud-sud
sud-sud wait for railway to enter
sud-sud wait for railway to enter
sud-sud have access to enter
sud-sud have access to enter
sud-sud: 0
sud-sud: 0
sud-sud: 1
sud-sud: 1
sud-sud: 2
sud-sud: 2
sud-sud: 3
sud-sud: 3
sud-sud: 4
sud-sud: 4
sud-sudleft the railway
sud-sudleft the railway
```

Comment: yes but what if i added 2 trains with the same direction then another train with a different direction? i want the third one get access as well when the 2 first trains left the railway .

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should establish a List and a thread each for the nord-sud and the sud-nord trains. The list threads should be responsible for getting the semaphore, then on acquire they should start the individual train threads (presumably adding a delay with each one after the first so the trains aren't running at the same time). The list thread should then call Thread.join() on each train thread (although in actuality it may only be necessary to join on the last one) and then release the semaphore after the last train has arrived.